# Unable to pass Set-PnPListItem a hashtable as value

Tags: sharepoint-online, pnp-powershell

Set-PnPListItem should set users in list fields but I can't get the format right. Usually, I would set it like documented, i.e. `@{"PersonField" = "user1@domain.com","21"}`.
However, in my case each list item could have different fields to be updated. Therefore, the hashtable might contain different key-value-pairs for each list item. That's why I need to be able to pass `-Value` the hashtable itself.
Now, trying to pass a hashtable like this results in ' The specified user could not be found.' :

[image]

It seems the error is not due to the hashtable containing multiple pairs. I tried a hashtable with only one pair and the error is the same. Could it have to do with the values not being treated as strings?

Do you have any idea how I can get it to work?
Thanks a lot.

EDIT:

So by trial and error I found a workaround but I have no idea why it has to be that way.

The way I populate the hashtable seems to make a difference. What's not working was:

**EDIT: So by trial and error I found a workaround but I have no idea why I have to do what I have to do for it to work. 

 Doing the following does not work with
 `Set-PnPListItem -List $list -Identity [...] -Values $updates`:


`$updates = @{}
if ($null -ne $currentSiteOwners) {
    $updates.Owner = $currentSiteOwners()
}`

 However, using the `.ToLower()` method makes it work:

`$updates = @{}
if ($null -ne $currentSiteOwners) {
    $updates.Owner = $currentSiteOwners.ToLower()
}`

 The fact that the `.ToLower()`method converts the id's contained in $currentSiteOwners to lower case cannot be the reason as they are not letters to begin with. The method must be performing some kind of string transformation that `-Value`ultimately accepts.

 Anyone any clue?**